# How do I change my local directory in eclipse to work with git?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Long story short I moved my local project to the root of my web server.  In doing so I've lost my connection to the local git files.

Here is the location of my Working Directory after pulling the source down from git.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\git\SiteName
```

subfolders are:

```
.git
android
website
```

My local webserver no longer has an android or website dierctory, but instead the contents of website are simply in htdocs.

Is it possible to reference the structure on github but keep my local files in eclipse in a different area, so I can once again merge and push files?

Comment: You have a local clone of your directories from github.  Is it that you want to work on them in eclipse and have them make changes in localserver/htdocs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell EGit to point to a local git repo from the Git Repositories view.  Once EGit knows where your repo is, it can import projects from that repo.  You can work on them in eclipse, but they point to the repo external to the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You could create symlinks to the files in the "website" directory inside your htdocs. That may or may not be what you want, since, all changes will be immediately reflected on the front end.

While importing a project, eclipse allows you to create symlinks to the files without copying them into the workspace. It's an option that appears after you click the "Advanced" button in the import dialog box. This should allow you to keep the files wherever you like, and still use them in eclipse.